# Create repetative rows by iterating between dates in two column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, python-requests

I have three column in a data frame

1. ID - A001
2. DoA - 15-03-2014 - Date of Admission
3. DoL - 17-08-2020 - Date of Leaving

Create three new column:

```
Cal_Yr - Calender Year
Str_Date - Start of Date
End_Date - End of Date
```

If the year of admission is less than 2015 than

```
Str_Date = 01-01-2015 else DoA
End_Date = 15-03-2015
```

I am dividing the year in two parts ... One part before anniversary date( start dd-mm of the year) and other part after anniversary date so that I can find weight of both parts ... but the date before 01-01-2015 should be revauled as 01-01-2015

I have to design a loop which create repetative 12 rows as shown in figure.

[image]

input table is:

| ID | DoA | status | DoL | Duration(years) | fee amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A23 | 02-Jan-16 | DH | 18-Aug-18 | 2 | 2345 |
| B23 | 01-Mar-09 | IS | 31-Dec-20 | 11 | 1000 |
| C23 | 16-Sep-12 | SU | 12-Jul-19 | 7 | 14565 |
| D23 | 01-Jun-20 | LA | 07-Sep-20 | 0 | 123 |
| E23 | 15-Sep-16 | IS | 31-Dec-20 | 4 | 6790 |
| F23 | 01-Jan-19 | IS | 31-Dec-20 | 1 | 7272 |

Comment: Please reformat your dataframe. Maybe you should use `print(df.tostring(), index=False)`

Comment: I need output as per image

Comment: Your output data doesn't make sense.  What's special about March 15 in the other years?  Why wouldn't you have "15-3-2014 to 31-12-2014", "1-1-2015 to 31-12-2015", "1-1-2016 to 31-12-2016", etc?  And why is 1/1/2016 included in calendar year 2015?

Comment: I have ti ignore

Comment: I have to ignore all the years which is before 01-01-2015. My dataframe should start from 01-01-2015 or more as per datain DoA

Comment: I am dividing the year in two parts ... One part before anniversary date and other part after anniversary date so that I can find weight of both parts ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want.  This is not a hard job; like most similar tasks, you just have to take it step by step.  "What do I know here", "what information do I need here"?  Note that I have converted to datetime.date objects for the dates, assuming you will want to do some analyses based on the dates.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = [
    [ "A001", "15-03-2014", "17-08-2020" ],
    [ "A002", "01-06-2018", "01-06-2020" ]
]

rows = []
for id, stdate, endate in data:
    s = stdate.split('-')
    startdate = datetime.date(int(s[2]),int(s[1]),int(s[0]))
    s = endate.split('-')
    enddate = datetime.date(int(s[2]),int(s[1]),int(s[0]))
    for year in range(startdate.year, enddate.year + 1 ):
        start1 = datetime.date(year,1,1)
        anniv = datetime.date(year,startdate.month,startdate.day)
        end1 = datetime.date(year,12,31)
        
        if year != startdate.year:
            rows.append( [id, year, start1, anniv] )
            if anniv == enddate:
                break
        if year != enddate.year:
            rows.append( [id, year, anniv, end1] )
        elif anniv < enddate:
            rows.append( [id, year, anniv, enddate] )

df = pd.DataFrame( rows, columns=["ID", "Cal_Yr", "Str_date", "End_date"] )
print( df )
```

Output:

```
      ID  Cal_Yr    Str_date    End_date
0   A001    2014  2014-03-15  2014-12-31
1   A001    2015  2015-01-01  2015-03-15
2   A001    2015  2015-03-15  2015-12-31
3   A001    2016  2016-01-01  2016-03-15
4   A001    2016  2016-03-15  2016-12-31
5   A001    2017  2017-01-01  2017-03-15
6   A001    2017  2017-03-15  2017-12-31
7   A001    2018  2018-01-01  2018-03-15
8   A001    2018  2018-03-15  2018-12-31
9   A001    2019  2019-01-01  2019-03-15
10  A001    2019  2019-03-15  2019-12-31
11  A001    2020  2020-01-01  2020-03-15
12  A001    2020  2020-03-15  2020-08-17
13  A002    2018  2018-06-01  2018-12-31
14  A002    2019  2019-01-01  2019-06-01
15  A002    2019  2019-06-01  2019-12-31
16  A002    2020  2020-01-01  2020-06-01
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "startdate can change quite a bit."

Comment: your code work only on list but not on dataframe. and my end date in year 2020 is 17-08-2020 but your output terminate on 15-03-2020 so it should hv one more row with str date as 15-03-2020 to end date as 17-08-2020. I have dataframe with thousands of IDs.

Comment: i asked solution with one sample data but to implement the solution on complete dataframe.

Comment: Listen, you have to do SOME of the work here.  The issue with the missing line was a one-word fix, which I have fixed above, but you need to take the responsibility to start with my code and change it to read your dataframe instead of a simple list.

Comment: thanks for the guidance Tim. I already modified my code yesterday and solved it.

Comment: your code was life saver. thanks for the guidance